# Story from a book of unusual fairy tales, about a beast that terrorized a village from a pond of milk

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, folk-tales

When I was a kid I read a book that had a collection of unusual fairy tale stories. One story was about a hero who wished to defeat a beast. This beast had made a deal with a village. The deal was that the beast would stop eating people and terrorizing the village if instead the village filled a pond with milk (possibly also honey, I can't remember) and brought it food. It would live in the pond and drink the milk.

The problem for the villagers is that keeping up with the needs of the beast was becoming too burdensome. So a hero decided to challenge the beast and was immediately eaten. Then the beast suddenly fell over dead, and the hero cut his way out. What happened is that the hero had learned that it was impossible to hurt the beast from the outside, so the hero had came up with this plan and practiced holding his breath in cold streams before confronting the beast. The hero used his knife to kill the beast from the inside and cut his way out. As a reward, the hero kept the two fangs from the beast as daggers, and freed the village from the oppression of the situation.

This wasn't the only story in the book, but the one I remember the clearest. Does anyone have any idea what the name of this story is, and what book of stories it may have come from?

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please check out the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] your question to add further details. For example, around when were you a kid? What language were these fairy tales in? Were they illustrated, and if so, in what style? How large was the book (both thickness and cover area)? Where was the book acquired from? Around how many stories were in the collection?

Comment: Hi ! Memory works in mysterious ways : So the more material to work with the more likely that something might click in someones mind . What of the other included stories , Was there any memeorable book cover art ?